# Not able to execute batch file from TCL, able to execute from cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, tcl

Hi I am not able to execute a batch file from TCL shell. I can execute it from command prompt.

```
C:\BTC>tclsh
% exec log/file.bat
couldn't execute "log\file.bat": no such file or directory
% exit  

C:\BTC>log\file.bat  

C:\BTC>plink -ssh -l root -pw hrun*10 5.1.5.8 iperf -s -i 1 -f m  

Terminate batch job (Y/N)? Y
```

As you can see, it is giving error in tclsh and it is getting executed in cmd.
Please help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the batch-file as code. Without any code it is almost impossible to help you without random guesses.

Comment: Did you tried an absolute path `C:\log\file.bat`? But perhaps tclsh can't start batch files, instead you need cmd.exe to start it `exec cmd.exe /c log/file.bat`

Comment: It is not helping

Answer (score 0):

Batch files are not quite directly executable on Windows; they need to be executed via the correct interpreter. The `auto_execok` (weirdly name for historical reasons) command helps with this:

```
exec {*}[auto_execok log/file.bat]
```

Comment: It is not helping

Answer (score 0):

I would think that all you need is to specify the interpreter and use a fully qualified path as Jeb mentioned.  His example though didn’t include the full path and since you didn’t mention where it is, I’m going to guess that it’s in C:\temp\log and you can just replace that with its actual location.
exec cmd.exe /c c:/temp/log/file.bat
Note the full path using the Unix style path separators and the drive letter specification.